# LifecycleObserver produce exception with methods that use newer APIs

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle, fragment-lifecycle

My `ViewModel` class implements `LifecycleObserver`.
When I call `fragment.lifecycle.addObserver(this)` it produces exception.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The observer class has some methods that use newer APIs which are not available in the current OS version. Lifecycles cannot access even other methods so you should make sure that your observer classes only access framework classes that are available in your min API level OR use lifecycle:compiler annotation processor.

Strange, that firstly it was working fine, but not long ago this exception has appeared. I've found, that `audioFocusRequest` is cause of this bug.

```
private val audioFocusRequest by lazy {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) AudioFocusRequest.Builder(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)
        .setOnAudioFocusChangeListener(this)
        .build() else throw RuntimeException("Can't be done for Android API lower than 26")
}
```

Does anybody know how it can be fixed?

**UPD**

Tried to use `annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"`, but got compilation error:
[image]
(decided to paste screenshot, because whole logs are quite big)

**UPD 2**
At the end I've decided to delete `audioFocusRequest` field and to use old deprecated method - `requestAudioFocus(OnAudioFocusChangeListener l, int streamType, int durationHint)` instead of recommended `requestAudioFocus(@NonNull AudioFocusRequest focusRequest)`

It helped me to make code working again, so it can be solution. But I didn't find answer - why this problem had appeared. It strange because code used to be working before.

So problem has been solved but question still stays unanswered

Comment: "GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more details" have you found anything of interest in the log?

Comment: Nothing at all.

Answer (score 6):

Try to use `kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0"`

Comment: Why should one try that, and how? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: I tried to use `kapt` instead of `annotationProcessor` and project didn't build at all, there was an error during sync

Comment: it's really help to me

Comment: I tried both `annotationProcessor` and `kapt` and both at the same time since the project is a mix of Java and Kotlin, and this doesn't address the issue

Answer (score 0):

The class which implements `LifecycleObserver` has some method, which has **parameters with type** that only exist for higher APIs.

Your *variables* (i guess) and *function parameters* must exist on all APIs even function is not called (maybe this is requirement for classes who implement `LifecycleObserver`).

A possible solution is to change function parameter type to `Any` (kotlin) or `Object` (Java) and cast it to appropriate type inside function.

Comment: As I've written - it was caused by `AudioFocusRequest.Builder(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)` and it recommends higher API. Finally I've decided to delete `audioFocusRequest` field and to use old deprecated methods for handling audiofocus changes. But I still don't know what exactly cased this error and how it can be handled

Answer (score 0):

I have to remove this set method on SpinnerView: lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by moving the offending methods into another class, but still called from my LifecycleObserver. After reading the error message again:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The observer class has some methods that use newer APIs which are not available in the current OS version. Lifecycles cannot access even other methods so you should make sure that your observer classes only access framework classes that are available in your min API level OR use lifecycle:compiler annotation processor.

It seems as though no methods or objects are allowed in the class extending `LifecycleObserver` if they don't exist in the device's OS, even if they are wrapped in an SDK version check and never accessed.